# Have only one Navigation Controller (and sub viewcontrollers) be in landscape

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uistoryboard

I have a storyboard app that is almost always in portrait. I do have one Navigation Controller (with 2 view controllers) that needs to be in landscape mode. It connects back to the main tab controller of the app, and all other view controllers and nav controllers in the app need to stay in portrait mode. I've tried setting orientation to landscape and allowing right and left orientations, but this unlocks all of the viewcontrollers to shift to landscape mode. Is there a way to allow only those 2?

Thanks for any help!
Ben

Answer (score 1):

You have to subclass `-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation` in every single viewcontroller of your app and only allow it for the 2 view controllers.
But for your tab bar, you need to also set it to YES when you are presenting those view controllers (you probably need to subclasse the tabbar to do that) and NO otherwise

Comment: thanks for the reply! I'm sorry- I'm really new to this. When you say subclass that line of code- does that mean in the .h or .m file of the viewcontroller? Or is it something entirely else? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: The better term is "override" that method.  Add it to your .m file.  It will replace the existing method of the same name that is inherited from the superclass (in this case UIViewController).

Comment: I think I understand- thanks! I read a little more- does this look right for the ones I want to be able to do landscape? `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}`

Comment: Yes you have to override it in each viewcontroller you want to be able to rotate but also on their parent viewcontrollers as it will only be called if the parent allows the rotation. That is why I think you need to subclass the UITabBarController to allow the rotation only when presenting the right VC

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't subclass UINavigationController !

For only LandScape Orientation use this in the ViewController Class that needs to be in Landscape:

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

This will keep your view only in Landscape Mode. Don't make a subclass of UINavigationController to put the snippet above in it ! It will cause all your views to remain locked in landscape orientation !

Hope that helps you out :) !

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried it out, but it doesn't seem to do anything. The views I placed it in stay in portrait, as do the ones without it.

Comment: did you subclassed your UINavigationController ? It should work, in my project works very well.

Comment: I didn't- UINav goes to a UIViewController (also no subclassed). This has a button that pushes to the UIViewController that is subclassed and has the code from above. About to try with a new project from scratch.

Comment: To add a couple of more details- the reason I'm doing this is I'm loading a video within a webkit in the view. I'd like for it to be able to play in landscape, not just portrait. Everything else in the app works great in portrait- just this one webkit (video).